How do I get the media player app in visual studio 2022 the legacy version to run after I have selected a file with my browse button
I have added the windows media player legacy version control onto my form and I have got a browse button to select my files but when I open a video or music file the media player doesn't play it. So I'm looking for code to make the media player to auto play when files are selected from the browse button.
this is my code so far:
namespace Zink_Video_And_Music_App 
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form { public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

            System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);

            //OR

            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);
            //etc
        }
    }

    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


  }
}

help with code please

You've stated Visual Studio 2022 but tagged the question with [visual-studio-code]. As it stands, the IDE doesn't appear relevant to the question either.
